# Is this a bug in Profiler or Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

Using Entity Framework 4 with stored procedures and SQL Server 2008 SP1... When running SQL Server Profiler (TSQL_SPs template), the lines that show my stored procedure call and its statements say that they executed in DatabaseID = 1 (Master) but it is actually happening in my application database (ID = 8). The procedures execute properly and return the data, and they only exist in my application database, so why does Profiler mark those lines as being in Master? Is this a bug in Profiler?  Is it a bug in EF4?

Note that running the same code against a SQL 2000 instance, Profiler correctly shows the application's database ID.

***UPDATE***:  I have now tested this on a new installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 and it still displays this as if it happened in Master.

***UPDATE 2***:  This has been logged to Connect at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/572246/profiler-reports-ef4-queries-as-occurring-in-master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned a work-around from [Olaf Tinnemeyer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410584/olaf-tinnemeyer):  Changing the *MultipleActiveResultSets* option in the Connection String to **FALSE** causes Profiler to properly report the query as being executed in the application database.

I still think this is a bug in SQL 2008, but I can live with the work-around for now.